# How to align VueJS components where one of them is a ThreeJS scene

Tags: css, vue.js, vue-component

I have three components: `Plan`, `Scene`, and `Controls`, and I want to align them as follows:

[image]

The challenge in my case is that the plan has to be in a transition as a sidebar, while the scene is a `three.js` scene, and I need to change the width of the scene according to the status of the `Plan` Open/Close, I have tried the [transition](https://vuejs.org/guide/built-ins/transition.html) with `css variables`, but I couldn't manage to achieve my goal, here is a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/variablescene-qf289u) to represent my problem.

Can you please tell me how can I achieve the components alignment as in the figure above? thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you trying to achieve something like this? https://kylebruns.xyz/Arcade I added an event listener that updates the size based on the canvas width and height.

Comment: @Kyrony more or less yes the same idea.

Comment: Sorry I don't quite understand your problem, do you want the sidebar act as an overlay? Or it will take up the space and change the size of the scene when user toggle the sidebar? I also don't understand about your attempt, are you having troubles adjusting animation of the transition or passing data around the components to change the width

Comment: @Remicaster "*it will take up the space and change the size of the scene when user toggle the sidebar*", and **both** "*troubles adjusting animation of the transition or passing data around the components to change the width*"

Comment: @Bilal for the passing data, have you tried using a store like `pinia`? Meanwhile for the animations you can try this method that I am using https://github.com/Kuon-dev/kuon-portfolio/blob/main/src/components/MainNavbarComponents/NavbarMobileComponent.vue (i am using animate.css dependency for animations)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to align the component using styling `css` from the parent view/component:

```css
:root {
  --plan-width: 15%;
  --plan-height: 80%;
}

#main {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#scene {
  position: relative;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: var(--plan-height);
  float: right;
}

#plan {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  width: var(--plan-width);
  height: var(--plan-height);
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #474444;
  left: 0%;
  top: 0%;
  scrollbar-width: 20px;
}

#controls {
  /* position: inherit; */
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 17%;
  /* margin: 1px; */
  padding: 1px;
  background-color: #575555;
}
```